# 2007 Sequioa stalling

Tags: toyota, stall, sequoia

I hope someone can help me. I got my sequioa 3 years ago. whwn i first got her ..every now and then when I go to drive her she would stall when I stopped. start right back up and after about a mile she would be fine  this didn't happen often.
now out the blue she dies and keeps dying when I go to slow down. I had a new battery installed and still no change. everything works just fine.  if I start her and just let her idle her battery gause will drop to 1/4 line and 500rpm but will run forever as long as she doesn't leave the driveway.
I never done a flush so I did a coolant flush and found a lil oil in it. I'm doing a gasket seal now but but I have no other signs of a blow head gasket.
everything else is just fine. nobody I mean nobody can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any codes? If so, what are they?

Comment: the only code is for a bank 1 sensor 2 heated oxygen sensor  forgot the actual code. but that code has been on for over a year since a shop had broke my 02 sensor